# R axis.POSIXct() at 10 minute intervals?

Tags: r, axis-labels, posixct

I want to plot a time series with a mark on the x-axis every 10 minutes.
Like: 
`09:10 09:20 09:30 09:40 09:50 10:00 10:10 10:20` and so on.
Signal was sampled at 10 Hz sampling frequency.
My data frame column df$t is class  "POSIXct" "POSIXt".
I tried with `axis.POSIXct(1, at=df$t, labels=format(df$t, "%h:%m"))` but I get too many labels. 
I think the solution is to use `at=`, but I can't figure out how to generate the array for it.

Comment: Is the column of the time. head(df$t)
[1] "2016-01-13 07:56:48 CET" 
"2016-01-13 07:56:48 CET" 
"2016-01-13 07:56:48 CET" 
"2016-01-13 07:56:48 CET"
[5] "2016-01-13 07:56:48 CET" "2016-01-13 07:56:48 CET"

Comment: Please make your question reproducible, and include all the necessary data / code to reproduce your problem. Instead of cramming info into the comments.

Comment: Very first example in `?axis.POSIXct` shows the use of `at = seq(...`.